# Python Regexes differ in Pythex vs. console

Tags: python, regex

I am using Pythex to test out two regexes, and I get the result I'm hoping for in Pythex, however, when I run these regexes against test strings in the console or while running the program, I don't get the match I'm expecting.

The first regex is supposed to check that the string has a pair of letters which occur at least twice in the string (but this pair does not overlap). So, "xyxy" and "aabcdefgaa" are valid, while "aaa" is not, since the a's overlap. Here is a link to the Pythex regex, where it's working: http://pythex.org/?regex=(.)%7B1%7D.*(.)%7B1%7D.*%5C1.*%5C2.*&test_string=qjhvhtzxzqqjkmpb&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0. and here is the console output of the same regex & string in the python console (2.7):

```
>>> import re
>>> pair_of_letters = re.compile('(.){1}.*(.){1}.*\1.*\2.*')
>>> string = "qjhvhtzxzqqjkmpb"
>>> match = pair_of_letters.match(string); print match
None
```

The second regex is supposed to check that the string has a pair of letters with exactly one character between them, e.g, "xyx", "abcdefeghi", or "aaa". Again, here's a link to Pythex: http://pythex.org/?regex=(.)%7B1%7D.%7B1%7D%5C1&test_string=qjhvhtzxzqqjkmpb&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0 and below I've pasted the Python console output:

```
>>> repeated_letter_with_one_between = re.compile('(.){1}.{1}\1')
>>> string = "qjhvhtzxzqqjkmpb"
>>> match = repeated_letter_with_one_between.match(string); print match
None
```

Does anyone know what might account for the discrepancy? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `{1}` is superfluous and can always be removed.

Comment: How should I specify that I want exactly 1 of character of any character?

Comment: It depends on the context. To match one `a` and then one `b`, the regex is simply `ab`. If you want to match one `a` and then any character except `a`, use `a[^a]`. To match any character only if it's not repeated, use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(.)(?!\1)`, etc., etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use raw strings to define a regex, or `\1` will be interpreted as ASCII 01.

```
pair_of_letters = re.compile(r'(.).*(.).*\1.*\2.*')
repeated_letter_with_one_between = re.compile(r'(.).\1')
```

To illustrate:

```
>>> "\1"
'\x01'
>>> r"\1"
'\\1'
>>> print("\1")
�
>>> print(r"\1")
\1
```